# Simple node app - mongo and local host are connected but page to db is just spinning and not loadin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apple-m1

Simple node app with mongo. Mongo and local host are connected but page to db is just spinning in browser. Inital page is loaded properly, yet the page that goes to the db just spinning and not loading. Mongo community is insatlled via brew + using mongo compass interface - on mac. Terminal output: Server started at port 3000
Successfully connected to database.

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/StudentDB", {
useNewUrlParser: true,
}, function(error) {
if (error) {
console.log(error.message);
} else {
console.log("Successfully connected to database.");
}
});

require("./student.model");
```

```
**index.js**
```

`app.listen(3000, () => {   console.log('Server started at port 3000') });`

```
I wonder what is missing...
```

Comment: what page are you opening? and what are you expecting content on that page?